# Android VpnService 'protect' method not working

Tags: android, vpn

I am using [VpnService] (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService.html)! and able to create VPN connection.  I could see (tracert) all the internet traffic going through VPN.

Now, my requirement is to bypass VPN for certain URLs (eg. www.google.com).  To achieve this, I have written the following code:

```
if (vpnService.protect(new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("74.125.225.241"), 80))) {
    Log.d("TAG", "Socket protection for google.com is successfull");
}
```

But on visiting www.google.com, I could still see VPN server ip on tracert.  So, with this code it seems VpnService is not protecting this request from going to VPN server.

Can anyone point me where I am going wrong and suggest the correct way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my understanding you only exclude (protect) one specific socket from the VPN tunnel.

Therefore every other socket you open with the same target is still going through the VPN tunnel. 
You have to call protect `prepare(...)` on every socket that is established from your device towards Google.

Comment: Thanks Robert for your reply. I am not opening any other socket.  Once I have vpn connection established, and protect method is called, I assume whatever I browse through android browser, will go through this vpn tunnel.  I confirmed this with tracert.  Could you please elaborate further your answer.  Also, if you can share some code how to do it, it would be of great help.

Comment: But in your question you write "my requirement is to bypass VPN for certain URLs", therefore you want to protect any socket that will be created to that URL/host and not the one you have created but never used. Note that each TCP/UDP connection from each App is a separate socket!

Comment: Yes Robert, your understanding is absolutely correct.  I basically want to protect certain URLs from going through VPN tunnel.  But, how can I get hold of sockets opening through other apps (basically browsers app), so that I can protect those sockets? Or if you can think of any other way to meet my objective, please suggest.

Comment: @shashank, If you want to be able to get a hold of sockets from different apps, you basically have to inspect all the packets and determine if the destination IP is part of the destinations you want to "protect". Then you have to create a new socket, protect it, and pass that datagram you intercepted through your new socket. However, keep in mind that the IP will only tell you the destination, not the URL. For that, you will have to read the payload of the data. And if the data is encrypted, you won't be able to tell the URL since you cannot read the HTTP headers.

Comment: @shashank, did you protect certain URLs successfully? please kindly let me know, thx:)

Answer (score 0):

You can get to know whether an IP address belongs to a certain URL(such as google.com) by inspecting the DNS query and saving the IP addresses which is linked to the URL you want to bypass. Browsers will start a DNS query first to get the IP address of the domain it want to connect to.